# Is it bad form to use default annotation for default arguments?

Tags: default-value, idris

In [the docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/miscellany.html#default-implicit-arguments), they show how you can use the `default` annotation to create default arguments, like

```
fibonacci : {default 0 lag : Nat} -> {default 1 lead : Nat} -> (n : Nat) -> Nat
fibonacci {lag} Z = lag
fibonacci {lag} {lead} (S n) = fibonacci {lag=lead} {lead=lag+lead} n
```

such that `fibonacci 5` is the same as `fibonacci {lag=0} {lead=1} 5`. They then say

> Note that while this works, this is not the intended use of the `default` annotation. It is included here for illustrative purposes only. Usually, `default` is used to provide things like a custom proof search script.

Is it problematic or bad form to use `default` to create default arguments like in the `fibonacci` example? If so, why?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for the Discord https://discord.gg/UX68fDs2jc